# How to set sound for Firebase notification when app is in the background?

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging, clean-architecture

I am developing an app where I am using Firebase cloud messaging. And I am using clean architecture. My FirebaseMessaging class is in my data layer. That class looks like this:

```
  @Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
    if(remoteMessage.getMessageType()==null) {
        sendNotification(remoteMessage);

}

private void sendNotification(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    NotificationCompat.Builder notification=new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.asp)
            .setContentText(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody())
            .setContentTitle(remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle())
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(0, notification.build());

}
```

As you can see my function sendNotification is for building notification when message comes to my device. And I must push this function through the layers to the presentation layer and then do all the logic for making notification. But I have no idea how to do that because function sendNotification hase argument that is Remote message and I cant push Remote message through domain layer because Domain layer does not support google-play services. Does anybody has idea how to push this function sendNotification to the presentaton layer?

Comment: you can use otto or eventbus for pushing events to presenter

Comment: Could I do something else? I know how to pass functions through the layers but in this case my biggest problem is that I don't know how to transform Remote message through the layers

Comment: Can you transform RemoteMessage into an Object that  you can pass around? That's how that kind of problem is usually solved in software development. It should be simple to do, RemoteMessage is really just a data object.

Comment: .Yeah that helps, thanks mate